# How to get PDO to select from more than one table

Tags: mysql, pdo

**Here is my code:**

```
$sql= ("SELECT R.cr_id,R.time,R.reply,U.user_id,U.user_name FROM tb_user U, conversation_reply R WHERE R.user_id_fk=U.user_id and R.c_id_fk='$c_id' ORDER BY R.cr_id ASC LIMIT 20");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$row=$stmt->fetchAll();


foreach ($row as $laww) {

echo $laww['$user_name'].":". $laww['reply']. "<br>";
}

}////END
```

I get only the result from $laww['reply'] but not $laww['$user_name']
Can anyone helpe me ?

Comment: OPPS ! thabks so much ! I start 2b blind  :)